# Python 3 Input Function and Sublime Text Build System

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, raw-input

I have a question on Sublimetext3 build systems. I have the following code(below) that takes a response from the user. I have Python3 installed and was using that as the build system. I had initially used the function `input()` since Python3 replaced Python2's `raw_input`. This compiles on Sublime text console.

```
start = input("Would you like to play? (Y/N) ")
if(start.lower() == "y"):
    print(start)
```

Since Sublime text is unable to take a response from the user I used the REPL for Python3 as the build system. However, I couldn't get the above code to work. It consistently gave me a

> ```
> NameError: name 'Y' is not defined
> ```

The only way I could get it to pass was putting a user input using quotations, ie `"y"`.

However, when I changed `input` to `raw_input` using the REPL build system it miraculously worked(see below). It seems like a mix of Python 3 and Python 2 since the print function `print()` still uses parentheses.

Does anyone know how to get an input without quotation marks? Can anyone explain why the code below mixes Python3 and Python2?

```
start = raw_input("Would you like to play? (Y/N) ")
if(start.lower() == "y"):
    print(start)
```

Comment: It's likely just python2.  `print(...)` is valid python2, it's just interpreted as `print (...)`

Answer (score 2):

In python3 `raw_input` was renamed to `input` and python2's `input` was dropped. Python2's version parses the input as code which is why you're receiving this error, you need to use `raw_input`.

Alternatively you can hack it like this so it's cross-compatible.

```
try:
   input = raw_input
except NameError:
   pass
```

you can also `read` from `sys.stdin` if you want a more organized way of doing it.